# Digikey OAuth2 API Connection

Tags: python-3.x, api, oauth-2.0, python-requests

I am trying to implement digikey.com API in my windows app. I want to search for part detail based on either partnumber or keyword.
I have tried below code but its not working, giving error. Where am I making mistake, please help.
I am not able to verify, they have mentioned something called sandbox and production application. Two different things. See documents here: https://developer.digikey.com/documentation/oauth

'''

```
import requests


client_id = '<client-id>'
client_secret = '<client-secret>'
redirect_uri = 'https://localhost:8139/digikey_callback'

auth_response = requests.get('https://sandbox-api.digikey.com/v1/oauth2/authorize', params={
    'client_id': client_id,
    'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
    'response_type': 'code'
})


auth_code = auth_response.url.split('code=')[1]


token_response = requests.post('https://api.digikey.com/v1/oauth2/token', data={
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
    'code': auth_code,
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
})


access_token = token_response.json()['access_token']


search_response = requests.get('https://api.digikey.com/v1/products/search', params={
    'access_token': access_token,
    'keywords': 'screw'
})


print(search_response.json())
```

'''

Comment: I tested auth_response  by Chrome and token_response  by Postman. Those works but search_response has error. `Invalid ApiKey for given resource` do you know the API documentation URL?. I searched it but just v3 version shows. It did not work either.
https://developer.digikey.com/products/product-information/partsearch/keywordsearch

Comment: @BenchVue I am getting exact same error. Documentation for SearchAPI: https://developer.digikey.com/products/product-information/partsearch

Comment: @PyCode please update if you have an answer. I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: @spd Still having the same issue.